# enemy follow player my "player" when it enters the "enemy" detection zone the enemy continues forward (to the left)

Tags: godot, gdscript

what is happening is that my "enemy" is not following the "player", when my player enters the detection area the "enemy" continues straight ahead (to the left).

thank you, if you understand something or need more information let me know

[detection zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AIpz.png)
[enemy code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUAcf.jpg)

enemy code:

```
const EnemyDeathEffect = preload("res://Bots/EnemyDeathEffect.tscn")

export var MAX_SPEED = 60
export var ACCELERATION= 25
export var FRICTION = 700

enum {
    IDLE,
    WANDER,
    CHASE
}

var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var knockback = Vector2.ZERO

var state = CHASE
var path: PoolVector2Array

onready var sprite = $AnimatedSprite
onready var stats = $Stats
onready var playerDetectionZone = $PlayerDetectionZone 

func _physics_process(delta):
    knockback = knockback.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, FRICTION * delta)
    knockback = move_and_slide(knockback)
    
    match state:
        IDLE:
            velocity = velocity.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, FRICTION * delta)
            seek_player()
            
        WANDER:
            pass
        
        CHASE:
            var player = playerDetectionZone.player
            if player != null:
                var direction = (player.position - global_position).normalized()
                velocity = velocity.move_toward(direction * MAX_SPEED , ACCELERATION * delta)
                print(direction)
            else:
                state = IDLE
            sprite.flip_h = velocity.x > 0
                
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func seek_player():
    if playerDetectionZone.can_see_player():
        state = CHASE
    
func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    stats.health -= area.damage
    knockback = area.knockback_vector * 100

func _on_Stats_no_health():
    queue_free()
    var enemyDeathEffect = EnemyDeathEffect.instance()
    get_parent().add_child(enemyDeathEffect)
    enemyDeathEffect.global_position = global_position
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide just move detection area and relavant code. It's just too much coding. Something might be wrong with state machine

Comment: ok, thank u , and sorry , do you have any idea what i could do? , sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I have no issue wit this amount of code. However, this does not seem to be the code we need. If I understand correctly you want the enemy to follow the player, but it does not. Which sounds to be like a problem with the behavior of the enemy, and thus we should be looking at the enemy code. Yet, you posted the player code instead, didn't you? Edit: if there is no code controlling the enemy, that would be the issue.

Comment: I've edited the post, thanks, this is my enemy's code, the detection code is in one of the images, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only possible culprit I see is this line:

```
var direction = (player.position - global_position).normalized()
```

Here `player.position` is in its parent local coordinates, while `global_position` as the name says is in global coordinates. You want this instead:

```
var direction = (player.global_position - global_position).normalized()
```

*I see this is the way you have on the linked image.*

Or if you prefer:

```
var direction = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
```

---

Aside from that, it could be that it is changing direction too slowly. Which - given the code - is the same as saying that the `ACCELERATION` is low, but that is for you to tweak.

---

I guess it is worth debugging that `playerDetectionZone` is getting the player, and the `CHASE` is working correctly.

Common approaches include using a `breakpoint`, or `print`. You already have a `print` for `direction`. Try also printing `player` to check the enemy is chasing what you expect it to chase.

For this particular case I also suggest to go to the run the project from the editor, and then go to the Scene panel on the Remote tab, and select the enemy. That would allow you to the properties of the enemy on real time on the Inspector. You should see the `state` change to `CHASE` (which would have the value `2`), and `velocity` should also steadily change.

Enabling "Visible Collision Shapes" form the debug menu may also help debugging.

If it is not working, double check the `playerDetectionZone` has `monitoring` enabled. Also check that the `collision_mask` of the `playerDetectionZone` and the `collision_layer` of the `player` are correct.

Comment: Thanks for all the information it helped me a lot and sorry for the newbie question but how do I enable playerdetectionzone "monitoring".

Comment: @AndréPimentel You have an `Area2D` as per this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUAcf.jpg - I believe that is the one you get here: `onready var playerDetectionZone = $PlayerDetectionZone`. Well, `Area2D` has a `monitoring` property. It is set to `true` by default, so you probably don't have to do anything. Still, if for whatever reason it is set to `false`, the `Area2D` won't detect anything. So make sure it is set to `true`.

Comment: Already enabled the monitoring by code and also the checkbox (it was already enabled as I said by default), and it still doesn't follow the "player", I put it to recognize the player by layers because by "get_node" it was not recognizing and it said " Node not found".

Comment: @AndréPimentel Does the enemy move when it does not detect the player? You say in your question that the "enemy" continues straight ahead. That could be it detected the player (you can confirm by having the code `print(player)`), but it is not able to turn fast enough. Which is what made me suspect of acceleration. Besides that, I don't know.

Comment: yes, it does continue forward but after the changes you told me to make to the code, it (enemy) passes me , and , after passing me it stays still even though I am inside the detection area , but whenever I I move he follows me, but he always stays away. Sorry if I wasn't 100% clear.

Comment: thanks for everything, I found the problem, the problem was that the point of the kinemetic body was not on top of the "player" but outside the map, that's why the "enemy" was always going forward, sorry for the inconvenience